# iPhone App to listen radio

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'd like to create an iPhone App that allows people to listen to radio. Below is what I've done so far, but when I click on the button nothing happen, can someone please advise what I've done wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RadioViewController : UIViewController{

IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
}

-(IBAction)radio;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIWebView *webview;

@end


#import "RadioViewController.h"
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
@implementation RadioViewController

@synthesize webview;

-(IBAction)radio{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://db5195728.tis.core.005.cdn.streamfarm.net:80/3212_erf_96_live.mp3"];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
    [webview loadRequest:req];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Are you sure the `- radio` method is called?

Comment: not if you a. either create the button using Interface Builder and haven't linked up the connection between its action and the method, b. or you're creating it programmatically and haven't called the `- addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` on it with the appropriate arguments.

Comment: Yes. Make sure that the method actually gets called when you tap the button. An easy way to do that is to insert an NSLog statement (like `NSLog(@"radio method called!")` at the top of the method. Then, build your app and touch the button. If you don't see the message in the log, it never got called. Also, unless you meant you're learning about nothing but how to navigate Xcode, I think you meant to call yourself "Objective-C Learner" or at least "{Cocoa,Cocoa Touch} Learner." :p

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your code. It works fine here. So:

1. Make sure your `radio` is called when you tap that button. You can set a break point there or add a `NSLog` to see whether it is called;
2. Make sure your `webview` is correctly add to your view:shown and of the correct size.

Comment: did it work? it's odd as mine does not work, have you added/changed something on the .m file?cheers!

Comment: It works, I've checked. Have you checked all the conditions I've mentioned?

Comment: I used another MP3 link because I can't access the MP3 link in your code. You can try this link http://db5195728.tis.core.005.cdn.streamfarm.net:80/3212_erf_96_live.mp3

Comment: I'm getting below error message when clicking on your link.
"Sorry, the website db5195728.tis.core.005.cdn.streamfarm.net cannot be found."

Comment: Could you put your project at some place and give me the link?

Comment: I've checked your project but I can play the radio! What's the problem you are having now?

Comment: Yes it works now... :) Thanks.
But when I click on "Done" the radio stops and the screen does not change. Since the "Done" button is within the webView, is there a way where I can either remove the DONE button and put my own control so that I can go on the previous page, or any advice on how to code the DONE button so that when clicked, it takes me to the previous page.